# JQuery фильтр с множественными категориями

Tags: jquery

Есть простой фильтр

```
$('.trainers__nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elems = $('.trainers__item[data-type="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]');
    elems.addClass('trainers__item_show');
    $('.trainers__item').not(elems).addClass('trainers__item_disable').removeClass('trainers__item_show');
    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'all') {
        $('.trainers__item').removeClass('trainers__item_disable');
    };
});
```

Как сделать проверку data атрибута у article, если у него может быть несколько категорий? Пример:

```
<article class="trainers__item" data-type="old student">
   <span>old student</span>
</article>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecj5n0rq/4/)

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался очень простым:

Вместо равенства в искомой строке нужно было проверять что значение атрибута ее содержит, т.е.:

Вместо `[data-type="` нужно `[data-type*="`

Comment: Надеюсь, Ваш ответ правильный))))

Comment: @LyubaIvanova под конкретно мою задачу он правильный)